# merging two document term matrices by row

Tags: r, tm, text-analysis

I have customer queries and answers from customer services in a csv file. I need to identify the subject of each question and then later develop a classification model on this. I have created two document term matrices (after cleaning the documents), one for questions and the other for the answers. I have reduced the size by only taking those terms that occur more than 400 times in the whole document (about 40k questions and answers).

I want to create a data frame that merges these two matrices by rows  and retain only the words that are common in question and answer dtm (and add up their frequency. How should I do this in R? I'll use the highest frequency word to label the question.

Any help/ suggestion on the approach is highly appreciated.

```
> str(inspect(dtmaf))
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 38697, terms: 237)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 326124/8845065
Sparsity           : 96%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
   Terms
Docs    booking card change check confirm confirmation email make port wish
12316       3    1      0     0       0            0     0    0    1    1
137         4    1      2     0       1            0     0    0    0    0
17618       4    1      0     0       0            0     0    2    0    2
18082       2    1      3     1       1            0     0    0    1    0
19141       3    0      2     0       1            0     0    0    1    0
21862       2    0      0     0       0            0     0    1    0    0
2756        1    0      2     0       0            0     0    1    0    1
27578       2    1      5     0       0            0     0    0    0    1
30312       4    1      2     0       0            0     0    2    0    2
9019        1    1      1     0       0            0     0    0    0    0
num [1:10, 1:10] 3 4 4 2 3 2 1 2 4 1 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ Docs : chr [1:10] "12316" "137" "17618" "18082" ...
 ..$ Terms: chr [1:10] "booking" "card" "change" "check" ...

> str(inspect(dtmc))
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 38697, terms: 189)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 204107/7109626
Sparsity           : 97%
Maximal term length: 13
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
       Terms
Docs    booking car change confirmation like number possible reservation return ticket
  14091       0   0      0            0    2      0        0           2      0      0
  18220       6   0      0            2    0      0        0           0      0      0
  20103       1   0      1            0    0      1        0           0      0      0
  20184       0   3      0            0    0      1        0           4      1      0
  21005       3   5      0            1    2      0        1           0      0      0
  24877       0   1      1            0    0      0        0           2      0      1
  26135       0   0      0            0    0      0        0           1      0      0
  28200       5   2      1            0    0      0        0           1      0      0
  2979       12   7      2            0    1      0        0           0      0      0
  680         0   0      1            2    0      1        0           0      0      0
 num [1:10, 1:10] 0 6 1 0 3 0 0 5 12 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ Docs : chr [1:10] "14091" "18220" "20103" "20184" ...
  ..$ Terms: chr [1:10] "booking" "car" "change" "confirmation" ...
```

Expected output is a matrix with (237+189) terms and 38697 rows. Matching terms in both dtms will have one column per term  and their frequencies summed up and the non-matching terms will be reproduced as such.

Here is a reproducible example with 10 documents:

```
> dput(datamsg)
structure(list(cmessage = c("No answer ?", "Hello  the third  number is . I bought this boarding card immediately after the operator has told me from the previous logbook the number  can not be found in the system. Therefore I request to return money. It was not my fault !", 
"Hi  I forget probably choose items on the   How can I do this now.  ", 
"Hi  I forget probably choose items  How can i do this now.  ", 
"Hello  I tell if I have booked . If not  is it possible and what would it cost? ", 
"First I wanted to transfer fromThen I wanted to know if you can spontaneously postpone the return ", 
"Hello. Does the have an exact address? With this address I do not find it on the navigation. Have an exact address where I can get the ticets. Where I get the Tikets then. Is the automatic chekin. Or do I then mot the tickets to the Chekin. Thank you.  But rather ask more questions. ", 
"Dear  booked everything again. Also the journey through In my previous message  I stated that it is a complete cancellation and I have booked the return trip. I do not intend to pay twice for travel. ", 
"Thank you. When will the new  registration show ?...as it still shows the . Thanks", 
"So my phone number is .Please tell me how this works."), afreply = c("Hello   afraid there is no space on the September. I have also checked but  are all fully booked. Would you like us to check any other dates for you? ", 
"Hello  As far as we can see the booking No was a valid reservation. We have however contacted  and can confirm that administration fee  was refunded back to your card. ", 
"Good afternoon  You are currently booked as high plane. You have requested an amendment to change the height   which will be more expensive. Could you please confirm the actual height of . We have cancelled you amendment request   please submit a new one with an accurate height ofreply to this message. ", 
"Hello  thanks for your message. I have checked and can see you have amended your height to on your booking. If you require any other assistance with your booking  please contact us.", 
"Hello  you booked any  In order to make a change to your booking  kindly send us a amendment request via", 
"Dear Mr. what dimensions  you want to take with you? here is only the possibility to change your departure for a change of booking fee and a possible ticket price difference. The ticket price difference can be requested  if you call us an alternative travel date.", 
"Dear Sir or Madam  we will send you the address ", "Hello  your crossing with was already refunded. As my colleague told you your  with  was still valid. In case you have booked a second ticket with   please send us the new booking reference number  but we cannot guarantee that you will be entitle to a refund. ", 
"if you can authorise us to take the payment from the card you used to make the we can then make the change.", 
"Good morning  we could not reach you by telephone. If you do not have we can send you an invoice via PayPal. The change can not be made until paid. . Do you want to pay the change to 1. "
)), .Names = c("cmessage", "afreply"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

corpus1<-Corpus(VectorSource(datamsg$cmessage))
corpus2<-Corpus(VectorSource(datamsg$afreply))
dtmc<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus1, control = list(weighting = weightTf))
dtmaf<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus2, control = list(weighting = weightTf))
```

Comment: Post example of wanted output

Comment: Just added the expected output in the question above

Comment: sorry, but this won't help anyone. If you want your question to be answered post reproducible example and example of wanted output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @PoGibas, I have added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way using the **quanteda** package.

```
library("quanteda")
packageVersion("quanteda")
# [1] ‘0.99.9’
```

First, we create two document-feature matrixes, and figure out their common terms:

```
dfm_c <- dfm(datamsg$cmessage, remove_punct = TRUE)
dfm_af <- dfm(datamsg$afreply, remove_punct = TRUE)
common_feature_names <- intersect(featnames(dfm_c), featnames(dfm_af))
```

Then we can combine them using `cbind()`, which (correctly) issues a warning that you now have duplicated features.  The second line selects just the common features, and the third line combines the identically named features in the dfm by summing them, which is what you want.

```
combined_dfm <- cbind(dfm_c, dfm_af) %>%
    dfm_select(pattern = common_feature_names) %>%
    dfm_compress()
head(combined_dfm)
# Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 6 features (41.7% sparse).
# 6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#        features
# docs    no hello the number is i
#   text1  2     1   1      0  1 1
#   text2  1     2   6      2  1 2
#   text3  0     0   3      0  0 2
#   text4  0     1   0      0  0 3
#   text5  0     2   0      0  1 2
#   text6  0     0   3      0  1 2
```

If you really, really want it back in **tm**, you can convert this using:

```
convert(combined_dfm, to = "tm")
# <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 10, terms: 49)>>
# Non-/sparse entries: 189/301
# Sparsity           : 61%
# Maximal term length: 8
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

**Note**:  You have not specified clearly that you might need to merge a dfm with different documents, so here I have assumed (from the example) that the documents are the same.  If they are different, that is also easily solved, but it was not specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
#dput(datamsg)
datamsg <-
        structure(
                list(
                        cmessage = c(
                                "No answer ?",
                                "Hello  the third  number is . I bought this boarding card immediately after the operator has told me from the previous logbook the number  can not be found in the system. Therefore I request to return money. It was not my fault !",
                                "Hi  I forget probably choose items on the   How can I do this now.  ",
                                "Hi  I forget probably choose items  How can i do this now.  ",
                                "Hello  I tell if I have booked . If not  is it possible and what would it cost? ",
                                "First I wanted to transfer fromThen I wanted to know if you can spontaneously postpone the return ",
                                "Hello. Does the have an exact address? With this address I do not find it on the navigation. Have an exact address where I can get the ticets. Where I get the Tikets then. Is the automatic chekin. Or do I then mot the tickets to the Chekin. Thank you.  But rather ask more questions. ",
                                "Dear  booked everything again. Also the journey through In my previous message  I stated that it is a complete cancellation and I have booked the return trip. I do not intend to pay twice for travel. ",
                                "Thank you. When will the new  registration show ?...as it still shows the . Thanks",
                                "So my phone number is .Please tell me how this works."
                        ),
                        afreply = c(
                                "Hello   afraid there is no space on the September. I have also checked but  are all fully booked. Would you like us to check any other dates for you? ",

                                "Hello  As far as we can see the booking No was a valid reservation. We have however contacted  and can confirm that administration fee  was refunded back to your card. ",
                                "Good afternoon  You are currently booked as high plane. You have requested an amendment to change the height   which will be more expensive. Could you please confirm the actual height of . We have cancelled you amendment request   please submit a new one with an accurate height ofreply to this message. ",
                                "Hello  thanks for your message. I have checked and can see you have amended your height to on your booking. If you require any other assistance with your booking  please contact us.",
                                "Hello  you booked any  In order to make a change to your booking  kindly send us a amendment request via",
                                "Dear Mr. what dimensions  you want to take with you? here is only the possibility to change your departure for a change of booking fee and a possible ticket price difference. The ticket price difference can be requested  if you call us an alternative travel date.",
                                "Dear Sir or Madam  we will send you the address ",
                                "Hello  your crossing with was already refunded. As my colleague told you your  with  was still valid. In case you have booked a second ticket with   please send us the new booking reference number  but we cannot guarantee that you will be entitle to a refund. ",
                                "if you can authorise us to take the payment from the card you used to make the we can then make the change.",
                                "Good morning  we could not reach you by telephone. If you do not have we can send you an invoice via PayPal. The change can not be made until paid. . Do you want to pay the change to 1. "
                        )
                ),
                .Names = c("cmessage", "afreply"),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA,-10L)
        )

corpus1<-Corpus(VectorSource(datamsg$cmessage)) # 10 docs
corpus2<-Corpus(VectorSource(datamsg$afreply)) # 10 docs


dtmc<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus1, control = list(weighting = weightTf))
dtmaf<-DocumentTermMatrix(corpus2, control = list(weighting = weightTf))
```

My code continues:

```
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
# rename anonymous document ids:
rownames(dtmc) <- dtmc %>% rownames() %>% as.numeric() %>% sprintf("doc%05d", .)
rownames(dtmaf) <- dtmaf %>% rownames() %>% as.numeric() %>% sprintf("doc%05d", .)

# transform to termDocumentmatrix
tdmc <- dtmc  %>% t() 
tdmaf<- dtmaf %>% t()

# introduce new first column "word"
tdmc_df  <- tdmc  %>% as.matrix() %>%  as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column( var = "word")
tdmaf_df <- tdmaf %>% as.matrix() %>%  as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column( var = "word")

# find common words
tdm_df <- tdmc_df %>% inner_join(tdmaf_df, by=c("word"))  
tdm_df <- tdm_df  %>% arrange(word)
dtm_df <- tdm_df  %>% column_to_rownames("word") %>% t()


# count occurences of matching words
colSums(dtm_df)

# find nonmatching words
dtm_df_nonmatching <- tdmc_df %>% anti_join(tdmaf_df, by=c("word"))  %>% arrange(word) %>% column_to_rownames("word")

# count occurences of nonmatching words
rowSums(dtm_df_nonmatching)
```

Common words, count:

```
 colSums(dtm_df)
 address     also      and   booked      but      can     card     dear      for     from     have    hello  message 
       4        2        5        7        3       13        3        3        4        2       12        8        3 
    more      new      not   number      pay   please possible  request    still   thanks     that      the     then 
       2        3        8        4        2        5        2        3        2        2        3       32        3 
    this     told   travel      was     what     will     with    would      you 
       6        2        2        5        2        4        7        2       25
```